# $this on multiple jquery ui slider's, giving undefined?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I am not a pro, it'll show in a second. I could initialize and separately handle multiple jquery UI sliders on a same page but when I try to do an ajax update on slider "stop:", if I refer to get my data-crunchid from the  of the appropriate slider, to be able to do an update for that slider, it gives undefined.

Is there a way to be able to pass on the data-crunchid to the ajax update? I guess so and I'd like to know what did I miss. I can't refer to the ID of the input, since it has to be dynamic, via the $this, to know which slider provides the adjustment.

Appreciated!

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfsgxck0/

Comment: Where have you initialized `score`

Comment: Nowhere yet, but it's not improtant now. We don't get that deep in the process, it'll be simply the .val of the slider touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g54aeu38/)**

You weren't referring to the appropriate element for the `crunchid`

I added `var crunchElement = $(this).prev('.SliderText');` because `crunchid` is an attribute of `.SliderText` and not `.RatingSlider`

Comment: And what'd be the proper element than, that is dynamic according to the slider touched? I "assumed" probably incorrectly that $this in this case is coming from the approrpiate input field... :/

Comment: Have you updated the fiddle? For me it's the same after refresh as well. Thanks though, I'll try the change also big thumbsup :)

Comment: `crunchid ` does not change anywhere. It would remain the same regardless of where the slider is.

Comment: It will, that's the reason I have to get it dynamically. Normally the data is php generated but wanted to strip down the issue for the "grabbing" of the data. It still gives NULL, but at least you showed me the issue, so I'll be able to finish it myself I hope. Fiddle i did not see any updates of.

Comment: So to clear everything, I know that it's static for now, the reason to handle it like this how I wanted is because many-many sliders will be generated on page with completely unique crunchid's.

Comment: Add the code and the link to the fiddle in your question itself and accept the answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: i was blind, the blue FIDDLE i did not notice till now :3 Thanks!